# What is the name of Google's tool to enhance page appearance?

Tags: google, meta-tags

Once I found one online tool from Google providing ability to indicate the designation of parts of page (i.e. product price, product photo, description and so on). This tool giving a HTML-code including all this information in `meta` tags. Now I need this tool but I can not remember how to find it on the Internet. Could anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you are looking for information on Schema. you might find this page useful. http://schema.org/Product

Answer (score 1):

Could you mean Data Highlighter in Webmaster Tools? https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=&v=WrEJds3QeTw

Comment: That's it!!! But I just can not localize the tool it self. Could you point me into the right direction?

Comment: It is in Webmaster Tools, under Search Appearance.

Comment: I've found it! But looks like previously (it was one or two weeks ago) I was able to access the tool with out signing in to the WMT and I received the result as the plain HTML code. Now I'm able only to publish the result.

Comment: @RomanMatveev Were you possibly thinking about [this](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets), in which you can click on the HTML tab, or run through a wizard of sorts (i.e., the second navigational link the left side).

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear but I think you're talking about Google's '[Products Feed Specification](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/188494?hl=en-GB)' which allows products to be listed correctly in [Google Shopping](http://www.google.com/shopping).

> [This](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/188494?hl=en-GB) page lists all the attributes that you need to provide in order
>   for your products to be listed in Google Shopping. Some attributes are
>   required for all items, some are required for certain types of items
>   (such as clothing) and others are recommended. Failure to provide a
>   required attribute may prevent that particular item from showing up in
>   Google Shopping results, whereas failure to provide recommended
>   attributes may result in items showing up less frequently. Read
>   through the entire document to make sure that your products show up on
>   Google Shopping. For a basic overview of feeds, see this article.
>   Before creating your feed, choose the file format that is right for
>   you.

Comment: Actually I'm talking about the tool giving the ability to load original HTML into it by Copy-Paste or by URL, specify the sections of your web-page (say this is product description, this - image and so on) and get the resulting HTML code

Comment: I don't think such a thing exists any longer, if it does it will be part of Google Merchant Center now. AFAIK you create the feed and google shopping picks it up from there.